# MySQL Select against String

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have a string "`Hello Help Me, Stackover flow, Google users, Google Plus,` ".
and in my database table I have

```
ID    TITLE
--    -----

 1.   Stackover flow
 2.   Google Plus
 3.   Help Me
 4.   Another Title
 5.   Hey World
```

I need to get IDs 1, 2, 3 using MySQL query, because the string contain those words.

Hows it possible in MySQL

EDIT

```
select ID, post_title, 
from wp_posts 
where 'Hello Help Me, Stackover flow, Google users, Google Plus,' like concat('%', post_title, '%') and post_type = 'mediawords';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `like`:

```
select t.id
from table t
where @string like concat('%', title, '%');
```

This does a string match, so substring can interfere.  If you want to take into account the delimiter (`', '`), then do:

```
select t.id
from table t
where concat(', ', @string) like concat('%, ', title, '%, ');
```

Comment: :) thats working :D an additional "," makes the error... Thank you u

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`in`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm) clause:

```
select id 
from table
where title in ('Hello Help Me', 'Stackover flow', 'Google users', 'Google Plus')
```